# Listing and formatting tagged data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm creating a list of texts with some tags associated to them **in Google Sheets**, each text has a "tags" column where the tags are separated by commas.

I want to have a second sheet where the individual tags are listed and the "texts" containing that tag will be displayed in a column next to it, each in their own row, leaving a number of blank rows in the Tag column until the next tag. Is this possible at all?

I know I'm probably doing an awful job at explaining so let me illustrate:

[This is my main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3CzA.png)

[This is my second sheet so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtXcA.png)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOpxC.png)

This is the function I'm using to list the tags individually (where tagsGrupos is the "Tags" column in the main sheet):

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPONER(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",tagsGrupos),", ")))
```

And this is the function I'm using for the "#" column which counts the number of appearances of each tag (where `tagsSeparados` is the "Tag" column in my second sheet):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SI(tagsSeparados<>"",CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(TRANSPONER(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",tagsGrupos),", ")),tagsSeparados),""))`

Edit: Here's a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oy3C5b0RA3UDsY8p4spdXzBSzKdlhCV4d86TPQZtXN8/edit?usp=sharing), it's the same as the original save that I replaced the hyperlinks with dummy urls

Comment: It's better to use English for the functions names or at list mention that the functions are in Spanish but copy-pasting to a spreadsheet set to use English will do the "traslation" automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following (where 'listaQuery' it's the range A2:F in the main sheet):

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), QUERY(listaQuery,"select B where C like '%"&A:A&"%' order by B"))
```

this mostly solves the issue except that:

1. It seems I have to add this code in a new cell every time a new tag comes up in the main sheet
2. QUERY can't handle hyperlinks, so the hyperlinks copied from my main sheet are converted to plain text

Is there some way I can get the same behaviour using just a single formula (also using functions that handle hyperlinks properly) in the top cell? I've been trying to rewrite this as a FILTER function but I can't manage to get it to work

Comment: It's fine that you shared you solution even it's not "perfect" but answers should not include follow up questions, they should be posted as new questions.